# How to go about creating a Q&A that becomes the basis of a beginnners brewing guide?

Tags: discussion, questions

So after [posting this question](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/12233/how-to-get-started-with-brewing-at-home) I was wondering about how useful it would be if there was a similar type of page that was basically a guide written on this forum for people like myself. Considering how useful it could be, it could have all the relevant details in the one page, or link to other homebrew questions like [this](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-equipment-do-i-need-to-buy-to-start-making-beer?rq=1).

Is this a valid idea, and how would one go about creating such a thing if it was OK?

Answer (score 1):

I think there's no need to reinvent the wheel.  We should just point people to the beginning info on the AHA website, or so other similarly "legit" site.

Comment: Agreed, though we could potentially make blog posts to this effect as well.